# How to overwrite grails command default script

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, gant

My grails project depends on another java project, before build grails project, i want to build the java project and publish to a local ivy repository.

I want to keep on using grails command line mode, so I want to overwrite the default behavior of grails refresh-dependencies, before resolve other dependencies, I want to build and publish the java project.

Is there way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered building your application with Gradle or any other build tools?

Comment: I want to overwrite grails default script, so can keep our existing practice, like we can keep using ALT+G to open menu to refresh dependency in STS. If there is no way to overwrite, we will use other build tools

Comment: You might be able to achieve what you want through creating scripts with the same name as grails scripts and put them in your project script directory. check commandline section of the documentation http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/guide/single.html#commandLine. however, building multiple projects would be better with build tools like gradle or etc.

Comment: Try it, but seems even I use the same name, grails still use the default one. I will use other build tool to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a good picture of how to use GANT scripts to add dependencies from other projects [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/commandLine.html#creatingGantScripts)

Have a look at "*Pulling in targets from other scripts*"